# "we say x is a variable ... " vs "we say that x is a variable ..."?

Tags: grammar, scientific-publishing

I am writing a mathematical paper and many definitions include statements like "we say **that** c is a constant ... "

My question: Is "that" really necessary here?

Comment: Mathematician here. I find the "we say" in your phrasing awkward both with and without the "that". If you [edit] the question to include much more of the definition you are trying to write we may be able to suggest better wording. Or look at some papers in your field and mimic a style you like.

Answer (score 2):

ignoring ‘we say’ since that seems oddly indirect for scientific writing, the use of that is optional since it is a [restrictive clause](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/clauses), modifying ‘we say.’ Since its purpose is to make the object of the sentence which is not the variable ‘c’ but that ‘we’ that are saying.

If the sentence were reworded to an active tense, subject verb object, then if it still had a ‘that’ then it would more than likely not be optional.